# Copy Constructor useless here?

Tags: java

Consider following situation:

I write a java program for an embedded(modem) device. The SDK doesn't offer Cloneable.
Therefore I have in `class GsmSignalStrength` the method `clone()`, but it's not
from `Object.clone()`, it is "my" implementation.
I would like to know is this useful and correct or should I use a copy constructor in `GsmSignalStrength`, like in the comment?
I don't see the advantage of a copy constructor, because I will have to create another GsmSignalStrength object in my StateMachine.

Here is my code...

File 1 "Status.java":

```
class Status
{
    Status(GsmSignalStrength gsmSignalStrength)
    {
        initClass(gsmSignalStrength);
    }

    GsmSignalStrength gsmSignalStrength;

    private void initClass(GsmSignalStrength gsmSignalStrength)
    {
        this.gsmSignalStrength = gsmSignalStrength;
    }
}
```

File 2 "GsmSignalStrength":

```
class GsmSignalStrength
{
    GsmSignalStrength(byte signalStrength)
    {
        initClass(signalStrength);
    }

    GsmSignalStrength()
    {
        initClass(100);
    }

    byte value;

    public void copyTo(GsmSignalStrength destination)
    {
        destination.value = this.value;
    }

    public GsmSignalStrength clone()
    {
        GsmSignalStrength clonedValue = new GsmSignalStrength();

        this.copyTo(clonedValue);

        return clonedValue;
    }

    /* With copy constructor
        GsmSignalStrength(GsmSignalStrength gsmSignalStrength)
        {
            gsmSignalStrength.value = value;
        }
    */

    private void initClass(byte signalStrength)
    {
        this.value = signalStrength;
    }
}
```

File 5 "GsmModemHandler":

```
class GsmModemHandler
{
    GsmModemHandler()
    {
        initClass();
    }

    private GsmSignalStrength m_gsmSignalStrength;

    GsmSignalStrength getGsmSignalStrength()
    {

        ...bla...

        return m_gsmSignalStrength;
    }

    private void initClass()
    {
        m_gsmSignalStrength = new GsmSignalStrength();
    }
}
```

File 4 "StateMachine":

```
class StateMachine
{
    StateMachine(GsmModemHandler gsmModemHandler)
    {
        initClass(gsmModemHandler);
    }

    private GsmModemHandler m_gsmModemHandler;

    void doSomething()
    {
        GsmSignalStrength gsmSignalStrength = m_gsmModemHandler.getGsmSignalStrength();
        Status xy = new Status(gsmSignalStrength.clone());

        /* With copy constructor

            GsmSignalStrength gsmSignalStrengthCopy = new GsmSignalStrength(gsmSignalStrength);
            Status xy = new Status(gsmSignalStrengthCopy);
        */
    }

    private void initClass(GsmModemHandler gsmModemHandler)
    {
        m_gsmModemHandler = gsmModemHandler;
    }
}
```

Comment: I never heard about the term "*copy constructor*" in Java.

Comment: This is a better question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com. @Lion: your point? It's completely possible to create copy constructors in Java.

Comment: http://books.google.ch/books?id=zmocDh06U6kC&pg=PA1049&lpg=PA1049&dq=bruce+eckel+tij+copy+constructor&source=bl&ots=2JyqBOqNsL&sig=vl3ZjzI3vdVQKmP1d22VDWZTcz0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=LKWFT7ioK9CM4gSd36zqBw&ved=0CCIQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL Copy constructors C++ style are often useless in Java.

Comment: Your commented out copy constructor in [File 2 "GsmSignalStrength"] isn't "copy constructing". It's just making the param that you pass equal to this. Java's "pass by value" method parameter passing means that this will be lost when you exit the method. Also, while it's not right anyway, doing `gsmSignalStrength = this` isn't going to create a new object based on `this`. The `this` is the object you've called the constructor on. If this worked (if java did "pass by reference") you'd be "assigning" the object you'd constructed to a new pointer (the parameter). This wouldn't be a copy.

Comment: edited the wrong code, thx wmorrison365.

Comment: The term "copy constructor" exists in Java (why wouldn't it?). Read Bloch's `Effective Java` page 61: "A fine approach to object copying is to provide a copy constructor or copy factory". He provides a good point on why this is preferred over the dirty Cloneable thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you <del>have</del> had in that comment,

```
GsmSignalStrength(GsmSignalStrength gsmSignalStrength)
    {
        gsmSignalStrength = this;
    }
```

is not a copy constructor. The line

```
gsmSignalStrength = this;
```

has no effect at all because all it does is move a method-local reference to point to `this`.

A functioning "copy constructor" would be something like

```
GsmSignalStrength(GsmSignalStrength gsmSignalStrength)
    {
        this.value = gsmSignalStrength.value;
    }
```

the point being to create an independent object with the same member variables as the original.

Also, unlike in C++, writing

```
object1 = object2;
```

does **not** invoke a copy constructor. All it does is copies the reference -- you end up with two references pointing to the same object.
If you want to create a new object you have to invoke the constructor explicitly:

```
object1 = new GsmSignalStrength( object2 );
```

---

As of whether it is "useless", that depends on your application. A copy constructor, a `clone()` method, and your `copyTo` method all accomplish the same basic task. You can create a new object with the constructor, or with `clone()`, or create a new object and use `copyTo` on it -- pick one way to do what you want and stick with it.

Comment: OK, you are absolutely right. But shouldn't it be gsmSignalStrength.value = this.value; ???

Comment: @arge No, that would be assigning the value of `this.value`, which wasn't initialized yet (so 0 since it's a `byte`), to `gsmSignalStrength.value`. You don't want to change `gsmSignalStrength` -- you're copying from it to `this`.

Comment: The difference between constructor vs clone being primarily in inheritance possibilities, i.e. if you create a CdmaSignalStrength as "extends GsmSignalStrength" your copy constructor won't be inherited while your clone() method will.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should just use clone, but do so carefully. 
Joshua Bloch's Effective Java states you should use clone judiciously as it's a weak interface and provides no method contract to support the activity. You're also dependent on well-behaved superclass clone behaviour (that is, superclasses use `super#clone` rather than using a class constructor to create the object (which would create an intance of the wrong class). **Note that this is what you've done in your File 2 example** - In a non-final class, you'd break any cloning subclasses.

Note that your clone (and each superclass clone) should provide full copies of all ivars. Now beware that you may need to make deep copies of things such as arrays and Lists - that is, create a new instance of the array and add new copies of elements in your own list. This is a "deep copy", as opposed to a "shallow copy". The clone should not share the same data as the original object (though you can probably debate this on a case by case basis).

Also, I don't think there's anything wrong with a copy constructor notion so long as it's well documented what your copy does (e.g. deep versus shallow copy).

Sample code for your example would be:

```
public class GSMSignalStrength implements Cloneable {
    ...
    public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        GSMSignalStrength result = (GSMSignalStrength)super.clone();
        result.setValue(this.value);
        result.setAnyOldArray(this.deepCopyMyAnyOldArray());
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Hope this helps!

p.s. Not reviewed Cloneable in terms of generics so you may be able to add type-safety around that. In fact, I've never really implemented cloneable at all. In the past (Obj-C world, we did do a lot of cop-constructing in a graphics package and got tied right up with our object graph - when to deep and when to shallow copy). V.complicated.

Comment: No need to be careful since in its embedded JDK there's no cloneable (Unless he is providing a custom `Cloneable` framework with a similar behavior as JavaSE's, but I think it is not the case).

Comment: Ah, ok. Thanks for the pointer. I wasn't aware of that. If he is implementing his own clone mechanism, he'll still have to avoid creating an instance of your specific class so as not to break  cloning for subclasses.